# How to get all loaded DLLs in my process?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

**Project folder path:** `F:\workspace\VantageAddin\aiscreenshotaddin\src\AIScreenshotAddin\bin\x64\Release\AIScreenshot`

**Files in above folder:**

- app.exe
- 1.dll
- 2.dll
- 3.dll

**Question description:**

In my Wpf project folder, there is one **app.exe** and several DLL files (**e.g. 1.dll, 2.dll, 3.dll**) together. And **app.exe** will load some of them (not all) into its process space.

All the exe and DLL files are signed. I need to check which Dll file is loaded and then check its signature. If all loaded DLL files are signed, then continue the main function.

This is to prevent that attacher might replace some DLL file, or put a not-signed DLL file in the project folder. So I won't check all DLL files in the folder, but only check those loaded.

I use below code to get the loaded DLL info.

```
    Process myProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    foreach (ProcessModule module in myProcess.Modules)
    {
        Logger.Debug(ClassName, $", dll module, FileName: {module.FileName}, BaseAddress: {module.BaseAddress}, ModuleName: {module.ModuleName}");
        File.AppendAllText("D:\\111.txt", $"dll module, FileName: {module.FileName}, BaseAddress: {module.BaseAddress}, ModuleName: {module.ModuleName}");
        File.AppendAllText("D:\\111.txt", Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

The result is below. As you can see, only the first item app.exe comes from the project folder. And the loaded DLL files in the project folder( **1.dll, 2.dll, 3.dll** ) are not detected.

Why? And how to detect them?

```
    dll module, FileName: F:\workspace\VantageAddin\aiscreenshotaddin\src\AIScreenshotAddin\bin\x64\Release\AIScreenshot\app.exe, BaseAddress: 1790275420160, ModuleName: app.exe
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll, BaseAddress: 140723926794240, ModuleName: ntdll.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL, BaseAddress: 140723452182528, ModuleName: MSCOREE.DLL
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\KERNEL32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723902611456, ModuleName: KERNEL32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll, BaseAddress: 140723885113344, ModuleName: KERNELBASE.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\14.3.5427.3000.105\Data\Sysfer\x64\sysfer.dll, BaseAddress: 1615527936, ModuleName: sysfer.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723907002368, ModuleName: ADVAPI32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\msvcrt.dll, BaseAddress: 140723913555968, ModuleName: msvcrt.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\sechost.dll, BaseAddress: 140723895336960, ModuleName: sechost.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll, BaseAddress: 140723898482688, ModuleName: RPCRT4.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll, BaseAddress: 140723443662848, ModuleName: mscoreei.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll, BaseAddress: 140723900907520, ModuleName: SHLWAPI.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll, BaseAddress: 140723849461760, ModuleName: kernel.appcore.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll, BaseAddress: 140723720749056, ModuleName: VERSION.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll, BaseAddress: 140723401850880, ModuleName: clr.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\USER32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723915390976, ModuleName: USER32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\win32u.dll, BaseAddress: 140723883933696, ModuleName: win32u.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\GDI32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723894353920, ModuleName: GDI32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\gdi32full.dll, BaseAddress: 140723891798016, ModuleName: gdi32full.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll, BaseAddress: 140723884457984, ModuleName: msvcp_win.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll, BaseAddress: 140723889111040, ModuleName: ucrtbase.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll, BaseAddress: 140723419938816, ModuleName: VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll, BaseAddress: 140723419152384, ModuleName: ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\IMM32.DLL, BaseAddress: 140723893633024, ModuleName: IMM32.DLL
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\ole32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723901366272, ModuleName: ole32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\combase.dll, BaseAddress: 140723903463424, ModuleName: combase.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\Program Files\Cybereason ActiveProbe\Powereason_64\Powereason.dll, BaseAddress: 140723007913984, ModuleName: Powereason.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723896909824, ModuleName: OLEAUT32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\WS2_32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723907723264, ModuleName: WS2_32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723422363648, ModuleName: WSOCK32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL, BaseAddress: 140723871744000, ModuleName: IPHLPAPI.DLL
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll, BaseAddress: 140723875282944, ModuleName: mswsock.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\system32\wshunix.dll, BaseAddress: 140723697287168, ModuleName: wshunix.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll, BaseAddress: 140723877314560, ModuleName: CRYPTSP.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll, BaseAddress: 140723868008448, ModuleName: rsaenh.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\bcrypt.dll, BaseAddress: 140723890159616, ModuleName: bcrypt.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll, BaseAddress: 140723877445632, ModuleName: CRYPTBASE.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll, BaseAddress: 140723888521216, ModuleName: bcryptPrimitives.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll, BaseAddress: 140723843366912, ModuleName: uxtheme.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll, BaseAddress: 140723358334976, ModuleName: clrjit.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\shell32.dll, BaseAddress: 140723917094912, ModuleName: shell32.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll, BaseAddress: 140723851558912, ModuleName: windows.storage.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll, BaseAddress: 140723878035456, ModuleName: Wldp.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\SHCORE.dll, BaseAddress: 140723897761792, ModuleName: SHCORE.dll
dll module, FileName: C:\windows\System32\psapi.dll, BaseAddress: 140723903397888, ModuleName: psapi.dll
```

**More：**

The signature to check is like this below.
I guess it is not strong name related.
[image]

Comment: I think .NET runtime only loads DLLs on first use. Probably you’re running your code before you used any classes exported by these DLLs.

Comment: @Soonts Thank you for your reply! You might be right. I add the detect code in the very beginning of main().

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thank you! What mechanism ensure this - "In particular you aren't not able to load un-signed assemblies into a signed one. " ?

Comment: A signed hosting process enforces all other assemblies to be signed also. Actually its about Strongnaming not signing in the common sense. So question do you mean dll or actually just assembly? And by signing do you mean code signing(Authenticode) or .NETs strong naming?

Comment: @Ralf Thank you! Very clear. I need to further confirm whether my case is signing(Authenticode) or .NETs strong naming. I use online compilation and not very clear about the details. I will update later.

Comment: MakePeace's comment is not accurate, strong name verification is bypassed for locally stored assemblies, starting at .NET 3.5.  And not performed at all for .NET 5+.  This was done because the check is quite expensive, slowing down the startup of an app.  And because it is so pointless, and attacker with sufficient rights to swap in a malicious dll just won't bother doing it the hard way when they can simply replace the .exe file.  But the boss likes the perception of security, [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature).

Comment: Also take a look at [LdrDllNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/win32/devnotes/ldrdllnotification) which is exposed from ntdll. This will let you evaluate DLLs that are loaded after your initial scan.

Comment: @Ralf I update my main post for your question. Please check the last part: More.

Comment: Those signatures can be checked with the [winverifytrust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust) API. The thing @HansPassant mentions still applies. This check is also expensive (maybe involve checking revocation lists on the Internet) and the result stays debatable if there is any improvement securitywise.

Answer (score 1):

From a general standpoint, this is never going to work. You cannot look at the list of loaded modules and then decide to allow something or not because it is too late, the module has already had a chance to execute code.

If you have some sort of plug-in support in your app you should open the file first (deny writes) and if it passes your tests, you may load it and then close the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

`Process` only contain the information of win32 dll. For .net dll, you should use `AppDomian.GetAssemblies` method to obtain their information.

```
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        if (assembly.FullName == "Your target dll's full name")
        {
            // something you wantet to do
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I log all win32 dll and .net dll, but still some dll files loaded are not in them.

Comment: @TomXue That means those dll hadn't been load at the time or you application has more than one `AppDomian`.